# How do I overcome the Proxy server in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, automation, http-proxy, proxy-server

I am using the proxy server in my system, When I try to open a URL through selenium web driver the Browser starts but the URL is not passed in the address bar.

How to overcome the proxy server setup?

I have tried with the following code

**Code:**

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "172.16.13.13");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
```

What is the solution to overcome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I downloaded the latest version of selenium from the http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ website.

Then added those jars to the external libraries. It is working fine now.